# make[ ]: *** [ ] Error 1

Tags: shell, gcc, makefile

I am trying to compile a file on gcc and my 'make' command seems to throw an error.

```
Rishabhs-MacBook-Pro:binutils-2.20.1 Rishabh$ make
make[3]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
make[2]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
Making info in doc
make chew
make[4]: `chew' is up to date.
./chew -f ./doc.str  <./../opncls.c >opncls.tmp
/bin/sh ./../../move-if-change opncls.tmp opncls.texi
Making info in po
...
...
make[4]: Nothing to be done for `all'.
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.  -I. -I. -I../bfd -I./../bfd -I./../include -        DLOCALEDIR="\"/usr/local/share/locale\"" -Dbin_dummy_emulation=bin_vanilla_emulation  -W -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Werror -g -O2 -MT strings.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/strings.Tpo -c -o strings.o strings.c
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
strings.c: In function ‘strings_file’:
strings.c:419: warning: ‘stat64’ is deprecated (declared at /usr/include/sys/stat.h:466)
make[4]: *** [strings.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: *** [all] Error 2
make[1]: *** [all-binutils] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I think the problem could be with the gcc but I can't seem to get around the problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the `-Werror` flag on the gcc command line. As the output says:

> cc1: warnings being treated as errors

So either change your makefile not to include this or fix the `stat64 is deprecated` warning in `strings.c`!